# How to add --no-bundler command in azure build pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am having some trouble with running my function app in python. When i push the function directly through `func azure functionapp publish air-temperature-v2 --no-bundler`. This publishes the function directly to portal.azure and the function works as expected. However if i try to commit and push to the Azure repos and it generates its build, everything is successful but when I try to run the function, it gives a module name 'pandas' not found error. It works fine locally & online (using no bundler command). My question is, how can I add the no bundler command in azure python pipeline? My yaml is as follows :

```
# Python package
# Create and test a Python package on multiple Python versions.
# Add steps that analyze code, save the dist with the build record, publish to a PyPI-compatible index, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python36:
      python.version: '3.6'


steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: python HttpExample/__init__.py
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    verbose: # (no value); this input is optional

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1   
#- script: |
#    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
#    pytest
#  displayName: 'pytest'
#  ignore
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'zohair-rg'
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: 'air-temperature-v2'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    startUpCommand: 'func azure functionapp publish air-temperature-v2 --no-bundler'
```

I have even tried add the no bundler command as the startup command but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be related to azure-function-core-tools version issue, please try following and deploy:

- Please update your azure-function-core-tool version to the latest
- Please try to deploy your build using below command:

```js
func azure functionapp publish <app_name> --build remote
```

There was a similar issue raise sometime back, couldn't recall but this fix worked.

Alternatively , have you considere Azure CLI task to deploy azure function , here is a detailed article explaining the Azure CI CD using azure CLi for python.

https://clemenssiebler.com/deploy-azure-functions-python-azure-devops/

Hope it helps.